# Adding a video on top an image using ImageMagick or ffmpeg command?

Tags: ffmpeg, imagemagick

I'm trying to automate process of adding a video (with drop shadow) on top a a background image . The video size would be slightly smaller than the images. Both sizes are known and fixed.

Comment: If you mix a giraffe and a sheep, you'll get a llama  What do you hope to get by mixing a video and a still photo - a still photo? a video? an animated GIF?

Comment: a video... with the original video playing on top of a static background...

Comment: kinda figured it, not sure if it's the best, but this `ffmpeg  -i background.jpg -i video.mov  \
-filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=28:28'" \
-pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy \
output.mp4` kinda outputs smth I can start working on. I'm sure there are better ways to do it... Adding shadow proves to be more difficult.